# How to open a specific page when click on push notifications in Ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

I am new to Ionic I integrated PhoneGap push notifications plugin. I am able to receive notifications in Android and IOS. I would like to open a specific page when a user clicks on the notifications but I am not able to find any solutions. I even tried the link below.

[How to open detail page when click notification in Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226655/how-to-open-detail-page-when-click-notification-in-ionic)

Here is my code

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
    var push = PushNotification.init({
        android: {
            senderID: "61426985247",
            sound: "true",
            vibrate: "true",
            forceShow: "true"
        },
        browser: {
            pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
        },
        ios: {
            alert: "true",
            badge: true,
            sound: 'false'
        },
        windows: {}
    });
    PushNotification.hasPermission(function(data) {});
    push.on('registration', function(data) {
        $rootScope.deviceToken = data.registrationId;
    });
    push.on('notification', function(data) {
        $state.go("tabs.createevent", {
            "eventId": "createNewEvent"
        });
        alert(data);
    });
    push.on('error', function(e) {
        alert(e.message);
    });
});
```

Please help me out to solve the the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the [docs](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md) it looks like you ned to call the `push.on('notification', callback)` [function](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushonnotification-callback).

Then from within the function, you can make a decision where to navigate to within the app based on the payload.

This should take place in your `onDeviceReady()` so that it will happen straight away. Then just route to a page like you normally would.

Comment: see my code as i updated my question still i am not able to navigate to the specific page

Comment: You've gotta give me more here dude. Stick a console log in the `hasPermission` completion to see if it does actually have permission. Are you running this on iOS or Android. If iOS, are you being prompted to allow notifications. In both cases of Android and iOS are all your certificates set up? Check everything and stick console logs or breakpoints everywhere to debug this. Are you actually using that push service URL? Or did you just copy it from the sample code?

Comment: Your app is not switching the state, but the alert is working? You may want to try
`$state.go("tabs.createevent", {
    "eventId": "createNewEvent"
}, {
    location: true,
    inherit: true,
    notify: true,
    reload: true
}).then( function(statego) {
    console.log("success", statego);
}).catch( function(statego) {
    console.log("error", statego);
});`

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be within your payload.

If you want to process your push message when app receives in background, you need to format the payload like below

```
{
    to : deviceid
    data : {
        title : "Push Notification",
        body  : "This is a push Message",
        userId: 10,
      }
}
```

More Info here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#android-behaviour